# Change thickness of cmidrule

Tags: tables, rules, line

How can I change thickness of `\cmidrule` because I need it in my report.

Comment: You can set the optional argument like `\cmidrule[5pt]{1-2}` which would print a line that is 5pt thick. This information can be found in the [`booktabs` package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf).

Comment: Default width is `\cmidrulewidth`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\cmidrule` macro (which is defined by the [`booktabs` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)) can take an optional argument which you can use to define the line thickness explicitly. For example, using `\cmidrule[5pt]{1-2}`, you would get a line that is 5pt thick and spans over the first two columns. The thickness of `\toprule`, `\bottomrule` and `\midrule` can be adjusted in a similar way using the relevant optional argument.

Another way to set the thickness of `\cmidrule` would be do set the length for `\cmidrulewidth` which holds the default value for the thickness of any `\cmidrule` (thanks to Werner for pointing to this). Setting the default length might be a good idea if you want to redefine the thickness in more than one `tabular`. The thickness of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` is defined by `\heavyrulewidth`, while the thickness of `\midrule` is defined by `\lightrulewidth`.

Compare the following (totally unaesthetic) modified example taken from the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}} \toprule[10pt]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\ \cmidrule[5pt](r){1-2}
Animal & Description & Price (\$)\\ \midrule[15pt]
Gnat & per gram & 13.65 \\
& each & 0.01 \\
Gnu & stuffed & 92.50 \\
Emu & stuffed & 33.33 \\
Armadillo & frozen & 8.99 \\ \bottomrule[20pt]
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\setlength{\lightrulewidth}{15pt}
\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{20pt}
\setlength{\cmidrulewidth}{5pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}} \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2}
Animal & Description & Price (\$)\\ \midrule
Gnat & per gram & 13.65 \\
& each & 0.01 \\
Gnu & stuffed & 92.50 \\
Emu & stuffed & 33.33 \\
Armadillo & frozen & 8.99 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using the `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
One  & Two  & Three  \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth] % thick rule using booktabs package
One  & Two  & Three  \\
\cmidrule[4pt](r){1-2} % custom thickness of 1pt, trimming on the right side
One  & Two  & Three  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example Table}
\label{tab:example}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: colortbl is not used at all here other than  making the rule blue, which wasn't requested